# If $(X,\preccurlyeq)$ is a totally ordered set equipped with the order topology then which is the closure of $(x_1,x_2)$ for $x_1\prec x_2$?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, set-theory, examples-counterexamples, order-theory

Let be $(X,\preccurlyeq)$ is a totally ordered set equipped with the order topology and thus for $x_1,x_2\in X$ such that $x_1\prec x_2$ we let try to determine the closure of $(x_1, x_2)$. So I know that the set
$$
\mathcal S:=\{(x,\to):x\in X\}\cup\{(\leftarrow,x):x\in X\}
$$
is a prebasis for $X$ and thus let be $\xi_1,\xi,\xi_2\in X$ such that
$$
\xi_1<x_1<\xi<x_2<\xi _2
$$
provided that $(x_1,x_2)$ is not empty. So we observe that
$$
[\xi_1,\to)\cap(x_1,x_2)=(x_1,x_2)\quad(\xi_1,\xi)\cap(x_1,x_2)=(x_1,\xi)\\(\xi,\xi_2)\cap(x_1,x_2)=(\xi,x_2)\quad
(\leftarrow,\xi_2)\cap(x_1,x_2)=(x_1,x_2)
$$
so that if $(x_1,x_2)$ is not empty then $x_1$ and $x_2$ are adherent to it, that is
$$
[x_1,x_2]\subseteq\operatorname{cl}\big((x_1,x_2)\big)
$$
However I do not able to prove or disprove if the reverse inclusion hols so that I thought to put a specific question. So could someone help me, pelase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a well ordered set, for example.  Then $x_2$ is in the closure of $(x_1,x_2)$ iff $x_2$ is a limit ordinal, that is, $x_2$ is not isolated.  Thus in the ordinals, $(4,7)$ is closed, but $(4,\omega)$ has closure $(4,\omega]$.  In a well ordered set there are no downward sequences, so the left endpoint will never be in the closure.

For a general totally ordered set, the closure of
$(x_1,x_2)$ could be any of
$$
(x_1,x_2),\quad(x_1,x_2],\quad[x_1,x_2),\quad[x_1,x_2].
$$

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand why any neighborhood of $4$ does not intersect $(4,\omega)$ so could you explain better, please?

Comment: Oh, yeah! E.g. $(0,5)$ is a neighborhood of $4$ that is disjoint from $(4,\omega)$, right? So $4$ is not adherent to $(4,\omega)$, right?

Comment: Correct.  $(4,\omega) = [5,\omega)$ so we can see that $4$ is not in its closure.

Comment: Okay, thanks very much for the counterexample!